# How to read text file within library package

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I’m trying to read some text files located within my lib crate. File structure looks like this:

```
workspace
|
|-- MyBin
|   |-- src
|       |-- main.rs
|
`-- MyLib
    |-- src
    |-- lib.rs
    `-- text.txt
```

Alright so MyBin has MyLib as one of its dependencies. Within lib.rs I am using the `std::fs::read_to_string` function to get access to text.txt’s contents. But when I run `cargo run` on MyBin the relative path now starts within MyBin’s src folder rather than MyLib.

Any way to read text.txt even when calling `read_to_string` from another crate?

Comment: You can embed it in the binary. Does it need to be dynamically read?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman nope. just a static file. you're right, i’ll just copy paste the contents into a local string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using libraries you need to understand that your code is never actually run before it's linked to an executable that itself is being run.

`read_to_string` **does not** embed your files content at compile time in the lib /  executable it only tells the program that it needs to go get the file at runtime.

The `read_to_string` takes either a relative or absolute path to the file. I assume in your case you used a relative path. Relative path are always interpreted at runtime relative to where the executable is being run from.

As the comment on your post suggested if you need the `text.txt` file to you when you run the program you either have to ship it with the executable or embed its content in the library (maybe as an array of string).